# "gradle projects" can't find any sub-projects

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a simple android app with google sign-in using gradle. I am using command line and basic text editor. I am new to both gradle and android and I am having a hard time configuring the build. When I run `gradle projects`, I get `No sub-projects`. Build runs without errors and prints:

```
:buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.012 secs
```

The structure looks like this:

```
 - myapp/
   - app/
     - java/
       - packages.../
         - MainActivity.java
     - res/
       - layout/
         - layout.xml
       - values/
         - strings.xml
     - AndroidManifest.xml
     - build.gradle
     - google-services.json
   - build/
     - generated dirs...
   - build.gradle
   - local.properties
   - settings.gradle
```

My top-level `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And the `app` build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.an   droid.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

There is only one line in the `settings.gradle` : `include ':app'`.

I have tried replacing my gradle files with samples from other projects, and modifiyng `settings.gradle`, but with the same results. I have no idea how to fix this issue and build my project. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sub-proj needs " compile project(':app')  "

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved thanks to a comment by Robert, I needed to add a `compile project(':app')` line to the dependencies in my app-level `build.gradle`. I also needed to adjust the project structure (move the `AndroidManifest.xml` a level deeper).